# Why are the first 4 bytes of 64-bit addresses printed as 0x00000001?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, offset, memory-address, otool

I'm looking at the disassembly of some x86_64 code with Apple's `otool`.  Here's a sample of the disassembly, as outputted by `otool`:

```
0000000100055de4    movq    $0x00000000,%rax
```

Only the last 4 bytes in that offset, the `00055de4`, represent the file address of that instruction.  I can open a hex editor and navigate to `0x55de4` and the `movq` instruction is there.

However, I noticed that gdb only works when I include all 8 bytes in the address, including the mysterious `1`.  `break *0x0000000100055de4` works as expected, while `break *0x00055de4` never triggers.

Every 64-bit binary I have analyzed with `otool` shows this pattern.  It obviously doesn't apply to 32-bit addresses.

So, if `0x55de4` is the actual address, why do `otool` and `gdb` use `0x0000000100055de4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__PAGEZERO, the first load command in a 64 bit Mach-O binary, specifies a segment size of 0x100000000 in virtual memory.

$ otool -lV *binary*

```
command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000100000000
```

When you do `break *0x00055de4` your breakpoint ends up in this segment of zeros, which explains why it's never hit. `0x0000000100055de4` is the address of the instruction (found at 0x55de4 in the binary) when loaded into virtual memory.

For 32 bit binaries the __PAGEZERO size is 0x1000, which explains why the pattern does not apply.